# Second y-axis label getting cut off

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot two sets of data in a bar graph with matplotlib, so I'm using two axes with the `twinx()` method. However, the second y-axis label gets cut off. I've tried a few different methods with no success (`tight_layout()`, setting the `major_pad`s in `rcParams`, etc...). I feel like the solution is simple, but I haven't come across it yet.

Here's a MWE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 21})
ax = plt.gca()
plt.ylabel('Data1') #Left side
ax2 = ax.twinx()
for i in range(10):
  if(i%2==0):
    ax.bar(i,np.random.randint(10))
  else:
    ax2.bar(i,np.random.randint(1000),color='k')


plt.ylabel('Data2') #Right
```

side
plt.savefig("test.png")

[image: Sample graph with Data2 cut off]

Answer (score 146, accepted):

I just figured it out: the trick is to use `bbox_inches='tight'` in `savefig`.

E.G. `plt.savefig("test.png",bbox_inches='tight')`

[image: fixed now]

Comment: you can also use `tight_layout`.

Comment: In what context? `plt.tight_layout()` doesn't do the trick for me... Thanks!

Comment: For some reason, `plt.autoscale()` cuts it off too. I'm using version 1.1.1, if that helps.

Comment: this worked in conjunction with fig.tight_layout() for me, good suggestion.  I am using mpl1.5 I believe.

Comment: `plt.tight_layout()` and `bbox_inches='tight'` both worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same issue which `plt.tight_layout()` did not automatically solve.
Instead, I used the labelpad argument in `ylabel`/`set_ylabel` as such:

`ax.set_ylabel('label here', rotation=270, color='k', labelpad=15)`

I guess this was not implemented when you asked this question, but as it's the top result on google, hopefully it can help users of the current matplotlib version.

Comment: didn't work for me. The y-label was still cut off in the saved image.

Comment: `ax.set_xlabel( 'label', fontsize='small', x=0.4 )` You can manually set the `x` and  `y` values of the underlying `ax.Text` object; which defines a precise position.