# Why is Matplotlib cutting off my (very specific) axis label?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here's the bottom line: I need to make publication-quality plots with Greek letters and subscripts in axis labels. Yet, in some rather specific cases, the label gets cut off near the tick labels.  For example, I really need a label of $\alpha_-$ for some plots, but the bottom of the $\alpha$ gets cut off. Interestingly, this is not a problem for $\alpha_+$ (or many other labels).

On one hand, this seems like a display issue when using default font sizes -- the label is cut off when looking at output from Matplotlib, but looks ok after `plt.savefig()`.
On the other hand, I need nice large font sizes for publication, and apparently the issue persists after doing `plt.savefig()` with large font size (say 22 pt).

I am aware of some previous posts that may seem related (e.g. [overlaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774086/how-to-adjust-padding-with-cutoff-or-overlapping-labels), [savefig cutoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239261/matplotlib-savefig-text-chopped-off), [second axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288062/second-y-axis-label-getting-cut-off)), but they aren't quite what I'm asking about here.

A very short MRE shows what I'm getting at (Matplotlib version 3.5.1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc("axes", labelsize=22)
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])
plt.ylabel(r"$\alpha_-$")
plt.show()
```

[image: MRE plot]

A few things I've tried:

- Include `plt.tight_layout()` to adjust things automatically. Not helpful in this case.
- Increase padding, e.g. `plt.rc('axes', labelpad=10)`. This simply puts a large space between the deformed label and tick labels / axis. (Plus, this affects any x-axis label as well.)
- Insert a new line, e.g. `plt.ylabel(r"$\alpha_-$" + "\n")`. Similarly, just results in some whitespace without fixing the label.

I also noticed an odd behavior from a typo version of the last point: keeping the newline '\n' with the raw text block, `plt.ylabel(r"$\alpha_-$\n")`, shows the label as expected. But, obviously, I don't want some '\n' in my label. I realize I could possibly just save that figure and crop out the unwanted '\n' -- that would be a forced workaround and certainly not ideal.

This is clearly a very specific question -- I cannot reproduce the issue with any character or subscript besides $\alpha_-$.
But what's going on? Why does Matplotlib understand how to display $\gamma_-$ (and so many other choices) yet not the label I really need? Could this be fixed with a different version of Matplotlib? Since padding adjustment doesn't fix the issue, what can I do?

Comment: I don't see this issue with matplotlib 3.5.3 on Google Colab.

Comment: I have now tried with a couple of other versions of Matplotlib, including 3.5.3 and the new stable 3.7.0, to no avail. Any chance it has something to do with using Python 3.10.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If there is a "bigger" subscript, it seems to work better

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc("axes", labelsize=22)
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])
plt.ylabel(r"$\alpha_{x}$")
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### It's when the subscript is "-" that we get problems

[image]

#### If you become desperate, here is a hack that makes the whole alpha visible

```
plt.ylabel(r"$\alpha_{-_{_{_{.}}}}$")
```

[image]

Only if you look very closely do you see the tiny "."!

If that is still too large, you could add more layers of `_{}`.

Or you could find a character that appears blank. However the space charactor does not work for this purpose - I guess TeX is clever enough to know that it doesn't print any pixels.

#### One-off workaround

With your character being a minus, it does *look* like an underscore. So why not print it as a (non-subscripted) underscore? Would that make you feel dirty? If not:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc("axes", labelsize=22)
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])
plt.ylabel(r"$\alpha\_$")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding to my silly question!
I think using an underscore is the best workaround, with minimal dirty feeling. Small note: it seems your last block of code doesn't actually show the underscore approach.
I am still mystified as to the source of this issue...